# How does wireless communication like wifi connect to different clients?

Tags: wifi

Does wireless communications like wifi, where different clients get different data, use different frequencies for each client? Or do they use the same frequency, but with time-divison multiplexing and encryption, so that no client can understand what was meant for another client?

Comment: This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Wi-Fi_radio_spectrum Wikipedia article is a good place to start in getting answers to your question.  Doesn't really sound like an amateur "ham" radio question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wifi is packet-based TDMA/CSMA with all users for a given access point using the same frequency.